# jquery datatables how create complex table from js array

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables and would like to create the table dynamic from js according to the following example:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

How can i still use this API if i want to create some more complex rows such as

```
  <tr>
    <td><div class="checksquared"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" /><label></label></div></td>     
    <td>Title Name</td>
    <td>18769</td>
    <td>
        <span class="checkslide">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
            <label data-on="On" data-off="Off"></label>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="tip" ><a href="modalEdit.html?idEdit=edit" class="pop_box" title="Edit" ><img src="images/icon/icon_edit.png" ></a></span> 
      <span class="tip" ><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Delete" data-name="delete name" title="Delete"><img src="images/icon/icon_delete.png" ></a></span> 
     </td>
  </tr>
```

EDIT: my server side is ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the function `mRender` (http://datatables.net/ref#mRender)
It allows for returning whatever you wish (HTML in your case) and you have access to the whole row.

You could e.g. use this:

```
"mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
    return '<span class="checkslide"> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value='+data+' /><label data-on="On" data-off="Off"></label></span>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Might this can help...
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

in the link inside of **Server side (PHP) code** you modify your customized row as per your need.